# CSS li отступ от вложенности

Tags: css, padding

Как заменить данный CSS циклом, добавляющим +20px padding к каждому следующему элементу в дереве li? необходим именно padding!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#admindivisionmenu li").each(function() {
     if($(this).has("ul").length) {
      $(this).prepend('<div class="admindivisionmenu-child admindivisionmenu-child-close"></div>');
  } else {
   $(this).find("a").first().addClass("admindivisionmenu-without-clild");
  }
    });
    $(".admindivisionmenu-child").click(function() {
     
     if($(this).hasClass('admindivisionmenu-child-close')) {
      $(this).parent().find('ul').first().slideDown();
   $(this).removeClass('admindivisionmenu-child-close').addClass('admindivisionmenu-child-open');
     } else {
      $(this).parent().find('ul').slideUp();
   $(this).parent().find('div').removeClass('admindivisionmenu-child-open').addClass('admindivisionmenu-child-close');
     }
     
    });
   
});
```

```css
.admin-division-menu > ul > li a.admindivisionmenu-without-clild {padding-left: 20px;}

.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li a.admindivisionmenu-without-clild {padding-left: 30px;}
.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li .admindivisionmenu-child {margin-left: 30px;}

.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a.admindivisionmenu-without-clild {padding-left: 50px;}
.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li .admindivisionmenu-child {margin-left: 50px;}

.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a.admindivisionmenu-without-clild {padding-left: 70px;}
.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li .admindivisionmenu-child {margin-left: 70px;}

.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a.admindivisionmenu-without-clild {padding-left: 90px;}
.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li .admindivisionmenu-child {margin-left: 90px;}
```

```html
<div class="admin-division-menu" id="admindivisionmenu"><ul><li><a href="?divisionid=1">Раздел 1</a><ul><li><a href="?divisionid=2">Раздел 2</a></li><li><a href="?divisionid=3">Раздел 3</a><ul><li><a href="?divisionid=4">Раздел 4</a><ul><li><a href="?divisionid=8">Раздел 8</a><ul><li><a href="?divisionid=9">Раздел 9</a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="?divisionid=5">Раздел 5</a></li><li><a href="?divisionid=6">Раздел 6</a></li><li><a href="?divisionid=7">Раздел 7</a></li></ul></div>
```

Comment: А что собственно не так и зачем такое понадобилось?

Comment: border top должен быть у li во всю ширину!

Answer (score 1):

Так годится?

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="admin-division-menu" id="admindivisionmenu"><ul><li><a href="?divisionid=1">Раздел 1</a><ul><li><a href="?divisionid=2">Раздел 2</a></li><li><a href="?divisionid=3">Раздел 3</a><ul><li><a href="?divisionid=4">Раздел 4</a><ul><li><a href="?divisionid=8">Раздел 8</a><ul><li><a href="?divisionid=9">Раздел 9</a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="?divisionid=5">Раздел 5</a></li><li><a href="?divisionid=6">Раздел 6</a></li><li><a href="?divisionid=7">Раздел 7</a></li></ul></div>
```